# Robotium Android test a lot of applications with one test application

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I would like test a lot of applications with one Test application.

I would write in the same test application every test method for my applications..

For example :

I would like test MyBluetooth.class, MyWifi.class, MyGSM.class in the same Test Application but each class is in different package.

How I can process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android different packages means different applications. It is not possible with robotium as in the AndroidManifest.xml of test application you state which target application you want to test and that can not be more than one. An example of what it can look like:

```
<instrumentation android:targetPackage="com.example.android.notepad" android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />
```

For details:  [Check Question number FAQ#5](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/QuestionsAndAnswers)